# Windows CE UTF-16 encoding and "surrogates"

Tags: c, windows, unicode, utf-16, wchar-t

According to what i've read here and there, Windows CE is using UTF-16 (aka UCS-2) encoding for strings.

With this encoding any character below 0xFFFF in the unicode table can be represented using a single Windows wchar_t, and anything over that is called a "surrogate" that can take up to two wchar_t for a single "symbol".
Is this right ?

Now how does windows handle these "surrogates" ? Does it allow these "characters" to take more than a single wchar_t ? In that case there is no way to make sure than the N-th pair of bytes in the N-th symbol right ?
Or does it "truncate" and treat each wchar_t as a separate symbol, which could cause some symbols over 0xFFFF to be treated as two different symbols ?

Thank you. :)

Comment: "UTF-16" and "UCS-2" are separate encodings, and are not different names for the same thing. UTF-16 cannot represent characters above `0xFFFF` in less than 2 code units (UCS-2 cannot represent them at all). It's not clear what you mean by "symbol", but no UTF-16 implementation should treat a surrogate pair as more than 1 code point.

Comment: What I mean by symbol is what you would put at a single position if you were printing a string into a single dimension grid. These two are what I call symbols : `^` and `ê`.
Do you know if Windows CE is using UTF-16 or UCS-2 ?

Comment: Your definition of a "symbol" sounds more like a "[grapheme cluster](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)"; e.g., `ê` can be encoded with 1 or 2 `wchar_t` units. Windows CE has support for UTF-16: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904394.aspx

Comment: Btw i assumed that UTF-16 was also UCS-2 because wikipedia let me think that UTF-32 is UCS-4 : " UTF-32 (or UCS-4) stands for Unicode Transformation Format 32 bits.  "

Comment: Thank you. I deduce from what you say that the system's encoding is UCS-2 ?

Comment: The statement—"Windows CE provides Unicode surrogate support at the OS level and in Microsoft® Internet Explorer. The support is limited to surrogate handling and display; editing is not supported."—implies UTF-16, except for edit controls.